# Cannot start the Docker service using Ansible on Vagrant box

Tags: ansible, vagrant

```
---
- hosts: vagrant
  remote_user: root
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
        - name: Start service docker, if not running
          service:
               name: docker
               state: started
```

> ERROR:  fatal: [192.168.1.16]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg":
>   "Unable to start service docker: Failed to start docker.service:
>   Interactive authentication required.\nSee system logs and 'systemctl
>   status docker.service' for details.\n"}

I want to start Docker using Ansible to other host (Vagrant). I could ping with Ansible to two hosts. But it won't work with Vagrant host.

Have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: why are using root to connect to the servers and then become sudo ??

Comment: The play does not set `become: true`, so they are not using `sudo`.

Comment: What if you execute a `command: id` task, then capture and display the output? Is Ansible *actually* connecting as `root`? It's possible that inventory settings or command line options could modify this despite setting it explicitly in your play.

Answer (score 2):

### Root cause

The `remote_user` setting in playbook (`remote_user: root` in the question) is ignored when using Ansible provisioner in Vagrant with default settings.

### Explanation

There is an [important difference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) between "regular" variables and connection variables in Ansible with regard to precedence:

> Another important thing to consider (for all versions) is that connection variables override config, command line and play/role/task specific options and directives. For example:
>
> ```
> ansible -u lola myhost
> ```
>
> This will still connect as ramon because ansible_ssh_user is set to ramon in inventory for myhost. For plays/tasks this is also true for remote_user:
>
> ```
> - hosts: myhost
>   tasks:
>    - command: i'll connect as ramon still
>      remote_user: lola
> ```
>
> This is done so host-specific settings can override the general settings.

Since you are using Vagrant, it creates an inventory file in under directory `.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory` and by default (depends also on box's defults) specifies `ansible_user='vagrant'` inside, which means the `remote_user: root` is overridden by that default setting.

This is mentioned in [Vagrant docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html#force_remote_user) as well:

> `force_remote_user` (boolean) - require Vagrant to set the `ansible_ssh_user` setting in the generated inventory, or as an extra variable when a static inventory is used. **All the Ansible `remote_user` parameters will then be overridden by the value of `config.ssh.username` of the Vagrant SSH Settings.**
>
> If this option is set to `false` Vagrant will set the Vagrant SSH username as a default Ansible remote user, but `remote_user` parameters of your Ansible plays or tasks will still be taken into account and thus override the Vagrant configuration.
>
> The default value is `true`.

### Solutions

You can:

- modify your play by adding `become: true` to either whole play, or a single task;
- set `force_remote_user` to `false` in the Vagrantfile;
- set `config.ssh.username` to `root` in the Vagrantfile.

The first one being the preferable way.

Answer (score -2):

> Interactive authentication required
>   Seems like the user running the *sudo* command remotely requires a password for the sudo action and as there no terminal to provide it, it fails.

Try to use a remote user having the right to run sudo command without the need to authenticate.

You could also use "ansible_sudo_pass" to specify the password to provide remotely.